# Excel 2007. I can't enable macro when I open document for second time

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

The document work perfectly on my computer with office 365, windows 7. But when I copy it to another computer with office 2007 and windows 7, it start normally ( I enable macro and it make everything it supossed to do). But when u save it( macro enable), and open again I cant enable macro nor add trust location. Every help i find is about enabling macro's on file. But my problem is there is no such options in usuals places when I open file for second and next time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following would be worth a try:

Create a new macro-enabled file on the target computer (where you have Office 2007 installed).  Copy the contents of the original document and paste into your new document.  Now go into the VBA editor and copy the macro contents of the original document.  In your new document, record a dummy macro that does one simple thing.  Edit the macro, remove the simple thing, and insert your copied macro code.